# Close HTTP request socket connection

Tags: http, sockets, tcp, webserver

I'm implementing HTTP over TLS proxy server (sni-proxy) that make two socket connection:

1. Client to ProxyServer
2. ProxyServer to TargetServer
   and transfer data between Client and TargetServer(TargetServer detected using server_name extension in ClientHello)

The problem is that the client doesn't close the connection after the response has been received and the proxy server waits for data to transfer and uses resources when the request has been done.

What is the best practice for implementing this project?

Answer (score 1):

The client behavior is perfectly normal - HTTP keep alive inside the TLS connection or maybe even a Websocket connection. Given that the proxy does transparent forwarding of the encrypted traffic it is not possible to look at the HTTP traffic in order to determine exactly when the connection can be closed. A good approach is therefore to keep the connection open as long as the resources allow this and on resource shortage close the connections which were idle (no traffic) the longest time.